# Force on a coil inside of a voice coil

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

as a homework exercise we were given the following question:

Given the following voice coil:
[image]

With depth = 20 mm
Permanent magnets with B = 1.23 T, Ur = 1.1
The coils has 20 turns, I = 1 Ampere.

a) Calculate the force on the coil (the Lorentz force) using reluctance method
...

However, we could not figure out how this may form a voice coil and where to actually start. We are aware of the fact that calculating the reluctance may be done by using:

$R = \frac{l}{\mu_0 \mu_r A}$

And consequently, the lorentz force may be calculated using:

$F = NBIl$

However, we are unsure of how the power circulates the system (i.e. how to convert this model into an equivalent circuit with power source and resistance/reluctance components).

I am hoping someone of you may be able to give us more insight on how to approach this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal F =R_{total}{\Phi} $

The effective magnetic circuit is anticlockwise, starting from the $\odot$ through the coil, an air gap, a magnet, a stator iron, another magnet, an air gap, another coil etc etc etc. You have to calculate reluctance for all these components and sum them up like you do with a series resistances to get $R_{total}$. Note the similarity to Ohm's Law. $R_{iron}$ is 0 because of infinite $\mu_r$.

Use the following to calculate magnetic flux:

$  \Phi=  BA = \mu_0 \mu_{\mathrm{eff}}\frac{A N I}{l}$

where $l$ is length of the solenoid (1) and $A$ is cross sectional area of the solenoid which may or may not be a circle. Also unknown is the shape of the magnets. This information should have been given.